# Making the EventHandler perform two different actions

Tags: java, jbutton, eventhandler

I have this assignment where we must create a game similar to Candy Crush using model view separation. I have a 5x5 `GridLayout` with `JButtons` in each position on the grid. Each `JButton` has a random color icon called with a method from the model. Clicking on one of the `JButtons` must change the border of the button red and then clicking an adjacent button must swap the contents of the buttons, or the colors. I have a representation of a 5x5 grid in my model using `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` with the string being the file name used for the `ImageIcon`. However, I'm having trouble with the swapping portion. When I click on the first `JButton`, I can make the border red but clicking on another adjacent `JButton` highlights that button red as well and doesn't swap the colors. I'm not sure why my `EventHandler` isn't working. Could anyone help me?

This is my `Model` class:

```
private ArrayList<String> _imageFileNames; 
private ArrayList<String> _store;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> _currentValues; 
private int _firstX;
private int _firstY;

public Model() {
    _imageFileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    _imageFileNames.add("Tile-0.png");
    _imageFileNames.add("Tile-1.png");
    _imageFileNames.add("Tile-2.png");
    _imageFileNames.add("Tile-3.png");
    _imageFileNames.add("Tile-4.png");
    _imageFileNames.add("Tile-5.png");

    _currentValues = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    for (int x=0; x<5; ++x) {
        _store= new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int y=0; y<5; ++y) {
            Collections.shuffle(_imageFileNames);
            _store.add(_imageFileNames.get(0));
        }
        _currentValues.add(_store);
    }
}

public String setIcon(int x, int y) {
    return _currentValues.get(x).get(y);
}

public void firstClick(int x, int y) {
    _firstX = x;
    _firstY = y;
}

public void secondClick(int x, int y) {
    if (checkXAdjacent(x) || checkYAdjacent(y)) {
        String first = _currentValues.get(x).get(y);
        String second = _currentValues.get(_firstX).get(_firstY);
        String temp = _currentValues.get(x).get(y);
        first = _currentValues.get(_firstX).get(_firstY);
        second = temp;
    }
}

public boolean checkXAdjacent(int x) {
    if (_firstX != x) {
        if (x == _firstX + 1) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (x == _firstX - 1) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean checkYAdjacent(int y) {
    if (_firstY != y) {
        if (y == _firstY + 1) {
            return true;
        }
        if (y == _firstY - 1) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is my `View` class:

```
private JFrame _frame;
private Model _model;
public ArrayList<JButton> _buttons;

public UI() {
    _model = new Model();

    _frame = new JFrame("James Kang's Lab 10");
    _frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5));

    _buttons = new ArrayList<JButton>();
    for (int x=0; x<5; ++x) {
        for (int y=0; y<5; ++y) {
            JButton button = new JButton();
            button.setIcon(new ImageIcon("Images/" + _model.setIcon(x,y)));
            button.addActionListener(new EventHandler(_model, null, button, x, y));
            button.setOpaque(true);
            _buttons.add(button);
            _frame.add(button);
        }
    }

    _frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    _frame.pack();
    _frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void update() {
    for (int x=0; x<5; ++x) {
        for (int y=0; y<5; ++y) {
            _buttons.get(y).setIcon(new ImageIcon(_model.setIcon(x, y)));
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my `EventHandler`:

```
private Model _model;
private JButton _b;
private int _x;
private int _y;
private int _clicked;
private UI _ui;

public EventHandler(Model m, UI ui, JButton b, int x, int y) {
    _model = m;
    _b = b;
    _x = x;
    _y = y;
    _clicked = 0;
    _ui = ui;
}

@Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (_clicked == 0) {
        _b.setBackground(Color.RED);
        _model.firstClick(_x, _y);
        _clicked = 1;
    }
    else if (_clicked == 1) {
        _b.setBackground(null);
        _model.secondClick(_x, _y);
        _ui.update();
        _clicked = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would check if one of the adjacent (x or y) is red, if true swap to corresponding , if not, delete all red backgrounds, and set the current to red.